# Can we Get the latest activity of any user

Tags: discussion, users, user-accounts

Is their any way to get the latest activities of other any user as we can get ours? If there any way or is it required some privilege?

Comment: Isn't the activity listed in the activity tab of the user's profile page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're logged in, go to the user's page and select the Activity tab. It is sorted by time.

EDIT: You don't need to be logged in for this. So it certainly doesn't require a privilege.

Comment: +1 @S.L. Barth oops I didn't noticed that